# HTML/CSS: Centering after float element

Tags: html, css

I have a float element on the left side on my page.

Now after this float, I want to center the rest of the content.

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ETm93/13/

This is what I have now. I did float: left. I can do float: right to get it to the right side, but how should i get it centered of the space that is after the floated element. Example:

```
   IMAGE (that is floated) |                   stuff here in middle                 |..
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is it just text you want centered?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/htMgc/

Comment: @Adam almost, I have div elements with specified width that doesnt get centered. e.g see http://jsfiddle.net/htMgc/2/

Comment: @Karem - OK, what about http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/QbMmX/ ?

Comment: @Adam - nice one, I had difficulties again with another div elements, but then I used inline-block and it worked. Thank you, please write answer

Comment: @Karem - Wrote it as an answer. Glad it worked. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align: center` and `display: inline`

```
#profile_leftPanel{
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #666;
  margin-right: 20px; 
}

#profile_rightPanel_center {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#recentStatus{
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/QbMmX/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
#profile_rightPanel_center {
    float: left;
}
```

to

```
#profile_rightPanel_center {
    text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For text only, use
text-align:center;